# Laravel's URL::previous() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I started working with Laravel 4 and I'm appreciating the framework so far.
I was learning about the URL helper when I found an issue: when I try `URL::previous()` it doesn't show the last accessed URL but the root URL.

So what I want to know is: can I fix this issue somehow or I will have to do another way? Like a SESSION manipulation, which record and use the last acessed URL yada yada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL::previous` uses the header information stored within `referrer`, meaning the page that brought you to the page you are currently on will be the page you go back to.

Not only this, the referrer header is not always filled, so can be empty, which will in-turn lead to errors.

My solution is to come away from using this.

Either redirect back using a route of your particular choice i.e. explicitly define the back to go to the page they were on.

**OR**

If you are wanting to access the previous page access before the current page you are on consider using `onclick="window.history.back()"` as an attribute on your button etc.